# Не верные координаты начала графика

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, график, численные-методы

Как сделать так чтобы график начинался с точки (0:1)?
Мне нужно, чтобы график начинался именно с точки (0,1). Подскажите как это реализовать в `python`? Он у меня начинается с точки (0.5, 5.25).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#Метод Эйлера
x0 = 0
y0 = 1
xn = 4
n = 9
h = (xn - x0)/(n-1)
xlist = []
ylist = []

def function(x, y):
  return -2*x**3+12*x**2-20*x+8.5

for i in range(n):
  if i == 0:
    print(x0,y0)
  else:
    y0 += h * function(x0, y0)
    x0 += h
    print(x0,y0)
    xlist.append(x0)
    ylist.append(y0)

plt.plot(xlist, ylist, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Уберите один отступ у `xlist.append(x0)`  и `ylist.append(y0)`, чтобы они начинались ровно под `else`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то ответ такой:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#Метод Эйлера
x0 = 0
y0 = 1
xn = 4
n = 9
h = (xn - x0)/(n-1)
xlist = [x0]
ylist = [y0]

def function(x, y):
  return -2*x**3+12*x**2-20*x+8.5

for i in range(n):
  if i == 0:
    print(x0,y0)
  else:
    y0 += h * function(x0, y0)
    x0 += h
    print(x0,y0)
    xlist.append(x0)
    ylist.append(y0)

plt.plot(xlist, ylist, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

У вас массив начинает заполняться после расчёта первых точек x = 0.5 и y = 5.25. Вам просто необходимо в массив поместить первые две необходимые вам точки

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло) И как я до этого не додумался...